# Using RSpec to test for correct order of records in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm new to rails and RSpec and would like some pointers on how to get this test to work.

I want emails to be sorted from newest to oldest and I'm having trouble testing this.

I'm new to Rails and so far I'm having a harder time getting my tests to work then the actual functionality.

**Updated**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Email do

  before do
    @email = Email.new(email_address: "user@example.com")
  end

  subject { @email }

  it { should respond_to(:email_address) }
  it { should respond_to(:newsletter) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "order" do 

    @email_newest = Email.new(email_address: "newest@example.com")

    it "should have the right emails in the right order" do
      Email.all.should == [@email_newest, @email]
    end

  end 

end
```

Here is the error I get:

```
1) Email order should have the right emails in the right order
  Failure/Error: Email.all.should == [@email_newest, @email]
   expected: [nil, #<Email id: nil, email_address: "user@example.com", newsletter: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
        got: [] (using ==)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
   -[nil,
   - #<Email id: nil, email_address: "user@example.com", newsletter: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
   +[]
 # ./spec/models/email_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: You are compairing the `Email` class itself with an array. Where should the ordered array come from? `Email.all` probably?

Comment: I get the same error using Email.all

Comment: Not exactly. Try `Email.all.to_a.should == ...`.

Comment: I updated my code to show the error I get when I use Email.all.should. I get the same error with Email.all.to_a.should. Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code:

```
it "should have the right emails in the right order" do
  Email.should == [@email_newest, @email]
end
```

You are setting the expectation that the `Email` model should be equal to the array of emails.
`Email` is a class. You can't just expect the class to be equal to an array. All emails can be found by using `all` method on class `Email`.

You must set the expectation for two arrays to be equal.

```
it "should have the right emails in the right order" do
  Email.order('created_at desc').all.should == [@email_newest, @email]
end
```

It should work like this.

Comment: I updated my code to use Email.all.should but I still get an error. I don't want to include the order portion in my test. I want my test to fail then add the order to my model.

Comment: You don't need to test that ARel is working, and if you're relying on that to do the ordering, then you'll want to add a method to your model like `sorted_addresses()`, or a named scope, and test that.  If you plan to just call `Email.where('whatever').order`, and you're not encapsulating it in a method/scope, then test it at the controller level (or wherever it's used).

Comment: You haven't created emails. You are only building emails. Use 'create' method instead of 'new'

Comment: `all` is deprecated and you should use `to_a` instead. So the line should look like: `Email.order('created_at desc').to_a.should == [@email_newest, @email]`

Answer (score 0):

For newer version of RSpec:

```
let(:emails) { ... }

it 'returns emails in correct order' do
  expect(emails).to eq(['1', '2', '3'])
end
```